# How do I allow requests from a frontend server to a django backend to not be prevented by CORS

Tags: django

I have a frontend that sends requests to a django backend.

This is some of the contents in my django backend settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'api',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

When sending a request from the frontend which is being run on http://localhost:3000, the following error occurs on django:

```
Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:3000 does not match any trusted origins.): /get_user
```

I have also tried adding the following to settings.py in django:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

This causes the following error instead:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /get_user
```

Why is this error occuring if I have added the url to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS?

Comment: Did you install `django-cors-headers`?

Comment: yes it is installed

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to allow everything just to test?

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add allowed origin as well as whitelist origin. for detail you can read this geeksforgeeks article.

url: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-cors-headers-in-your-django-project/

Comment: still get the same error